# How to use condition in cplex?

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, cplex, linearization

I want to use conditions to my variable.

```
dvar boolean x[I][J][K][L]
dvar in h[i]
```

my code is

```
forall(i in IP, j in J)
  sum(k in K, l in L)
   x[i][j][k][l] - 7 == h[i];
```

The following condition must be satisfied:

```
if x[i][j][k][l] - 7 <=0, h[i] must be zero.
if x[i][j][k][l] - 7 >=0, h[i] must be calculated
```

How do we formulate it in the integer programming formulation on CPLEX?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Are you missing a sum in each of your two “if” conditions?

Answer (score 6):

In OPL CPLEX you can use [if then](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooifthen.mod) logical constraints.

For instance

```
range I=1..2;
range J=1..3;
range K=1..4;
range L=1..5;

dvar boolean x[I][J][K][L];
dvar int h[I];

subject to
{

forall(i in I, j in J,k in K,l in L)
 {
  (x[i][j][k][l] - 7 >=0)
  => (sum(k2 in K, l2 in L) (x[i][j][k2][l2] - 7) == h[i]);
  
  (x[i][j][k][l] - 7 <=0)
  => (0 == h[i]);
}
}
```

works

Comment: thank u so much!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to enforce $h_i = \max(\sum_{k,l} x_{i,j,k,l}-7, 0)$.  Some solvers will automatically linearize this.  Depending on where $h_i$ appears elsewhere in the problem, you might be able to get by with enforcing instead $h_i \ge \max(\sum_{k,l} x_{i,j,k,l}-7, 0),$
which you can do without introducing new variables, by imposing
\begin{align}
h_i &\ge \sum_{k,l} x_{i,j,k,l}-7 \tag1\\
h_i &\ge 0 \tag2
\end{align}
If necessary, you can also enforce $h_i \le \max(\sum_{k,l} x_{i,j,k,l}-7, 0)$
by introducing binary variable $\delta_{i,j}$ (as in the proposed formulation by @anjikum) and imposing
\begin{align}
h_i &\le \sum_{k,l} x_{i,j,k,l} - 7\delta_{i,j} \tag3\\
h_i &\le (M_{i,j}-7)\delta_{i,j} \tag4
\end{align}
Here, $M_{i,j}$ is a small constant upper bound on $\sum_{k,l} x_{i,j,k,l}$.

Comment: thank u so much!

Answer (score 1):

Below is one way to formulate it. Need to introduce another binary variable ($\delta_{i,j}$). $M$ depends on bounds of $h_{i}$ and $x_{i,j,k,l}$ :
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k,l} x_{i,j,k,l}-7 &\le h_{i} + M \cdot (1-\delta_{i,j})\\
\sum_{k,l} x_{i,j,k,l}-7 &\ge h_{i} - M \cdot (1-\delta_{i,j}) \\
\sum_{k,l} x_{i,j,k,l}-7 &\le M \cdot \delta_{i,j}\\
\sum_{k,l} x_{i,j,k,l}-7 &\ge  -M \cdot (1-\delta_{i,j})
\end{align}
$$
Regarding CPLEX code, you need to add these constraints similar to declaration in your code (provided in question).

Comment: This formulation doesn’t enforce the desired behavior when the sum is $7$.  In that case, $\delta_{i,j}$ can take either value, and $\delta_{i,j}=0$ allows $h_i$ to be free.

Comment: thank u so much!